# How do I get the user value selected in a date time component in ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am using Ionic Framework Version: 3.1.1 and I need (basically) a Two Way Data Binding but I have couldn't figure it out... I have this:

in **HTML:**

```
<ion-datetime (click)="toggle()" [ngClass]="prod" displayFormat="D" 
     doneText="I want" cancelText="I don't" 
       [(ngModel)]="days" dayValues="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10" 
        item-left>
</ion-datetime>
```

in **TS:**

```
days = 0;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {   }   

toggle(){
    console.log(this.days);
}
```

But when I choose a day, in the date time picker, and click on "I want" button, an empty string is showed in the console, any suggestion? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after reading a lot of posts and read the ionic documentation and components I could understand that the `displayFormat="D"` was the problem, it's invalid! therefore, nothing was assigned in `days`. I tried several ways to implement like a number picker using DateTime component of Ionic but I realized that it's not possible as I wanted, the `displayFormat` attribute require specific format (as it's showed [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/)) and just `D` was not proper.

I figured it out using [Ion Multi Item Picker component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ion-multi-picker). My code below:

in **HTML:**

```
<ion-multi-picker [ngClass]="prod" doneText="I want"  cancelText="I don't"
     [(ngModel)] = "days" (ionChange)="toggle()"
       placeholder=" " item-content item-left [multiPickerColumns]="quantityValues">
</ion-multi-picker>
```

in **TS:**

```
quantityValues = [];

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.quantityValues = [{
        name: 'col1',
        options: [
            { text: '0', value: '0' },
            { text: '1', value: '1' },
            { text: '2', value: '2' },
            { text: '3', value: '3' },
            { text: '4', value: '4' },
            { text: '5', value: '5' },
            { text: '6', value: '6' },
            { text: '7', value: '7' },
            { text: '8', value: '8' },
            { text: '9', value: '9' },
            { text: '10', value: '10' }
        ]
    }];
}

toggle(){
    console.log(this.days);
}
```

I hope this help for further questions :)